# set xPage component title/tooltip doesn't work for readOnly component

Tags: javascript, xpages

If I try to set title property by using SSJS formula for readOnly EditBox then it doesn't work. But it works for e.g. disabled EditBox. Is it as designed behaviour?

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="test value" readonly="true">
    <xp:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(!!viewScope.TEST_SCOPE_VAR){
return "tooltip 1";
    } else {
return "tooltip 2";
}}]]></xp:this.title></xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Did you try checking the box for Show Disabled Control for Read Only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlad,

If you check/tick the box to "Show Disabled Control for Read Only", then you can use a tooltip.  I prefer to display read-only values in this manner.  Otherwise it just writes as a computed field, or plain text in your source.

[image]

The screenshot is just taking your tooltip and adding it to one of my read only input fields with the box checked.